# Annotate facet plot with grouped variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid, geom-text

I would like to place the numbers of observations above a facet boxplot. Here is an example:

```
exmp = mtcars %>% as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(cartype = as.factor(row.names(mtcars))) %>% 
  group_by(cyl, am, gear) %>% 
  mutate(N = n())

ggplot(exmp, aes(x = am, fill = gear, y = wt)) +
  facet_grid(.~cyl) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_text(aes(y = 6, label = N))
```

So, I already created column `N` to get the label over each box in the boxplot (combination of `cyl`, `am` and `gear`). **How do I plot these labels so that they are over the respective box?** Please note that the number of levels of gear for each level of am differs *on purpose*.

I really looked at a lot of ggplot tutorials and there are tons of questions dealing with annotating in facet plots. But none addressed this fairly common problem...[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give `position_dodge()` inside `geom_text`to match the position of the boxes, also define `data` argument to get the `distinct` value of observations:

```
ggplot(exmp, aes(x = as.factor(am), fill = as.factor(gear), y = wt)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_grid(.~cyl) + 
  geom_text(data = dplyr::distinct(exmp, N), 
            aes(y = 6, label = N), position = position_dodge(0.9))
```

[image]

Comment: Great, this is a pretty neat solution without a lot of extra code needed! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 3):

One minor issue here is that you are printing the `N` value once for every data point, not once for every cyl/am/gear combination. So you might want to add a filtering step to avoid overplotting that text, which can look messy on screen, reduce your control over alpha, and slow down plotting in cases with larger data.

```
library(tidyverse)
exmp = mtcars %>% as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(cartype = as.factor(row.names(mtcars))) %>% 
  group_by(cyl, am, gear) %>% 
  mutate(N = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(am = as.factor(am),
         gear = as.factor(gear))
```

(The data prep above was necessary for me to get the plot to look like your example. I'm using tidyverse 1.2.1 and ggplot2 3.2.1)

```
ggplot(exmp, aes(x = am, fill = gear, y = wt, 
                 group = interaction(gear, am))) +
  facet_grid(.~cyl) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_text(data = exmp %>% distinct(cyl, gear, am, N),
            aes(y = 6, label = N),
            position = position_dodge(width = 0.8))
```

[image]

Here's the same chart with overplotting:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Pretty neat to use the interaction as ``group``! I would accept your answer  if I could accept two ;)

Comment: Actually, I tried it out with my real data and the interaction term doesn't change anything. What it is intended for?

Comment: For me, that changed the dodging behavior. Behavior for that might vary between ggplot versions.

Comment: Ok, good to know. Will keep this in mind if a plot doesn't turn as I want ;)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps using `position_dodge()` in your `geom_text()` will get you what you want?

```
mtcars %>% as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(cartype = as.factor(row.names(mtcars))) %>% 
  group_by(cyl, am, gear) %>% 
  mutate(N = n()) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = as.factor(am), fill = as.factor(gear), y = wt)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_text(aes(y = 6, label = N), position = position_dodge(width = 0.7)) +
  facet_grid(.~cyl)
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution! Also nice to know that you could actually pipe a whole ggplot to a data.frame... The only problem as with the solution by Jon Spring is that there are multiple labels plotted on top of each other. This looks kind of ugly because they are thicker than others.